langchain-community OpenSearchVectorSearch return all the data as vectors
Need all the store vectors from opensearchvectorsearch from langchain, I am splitting, embedding and store the documents in the open search, now i want to run clustering on those store vectors but when i am trying to get all data it will return using similarity in document format there is any way to get those result in vectors form
sample code
!pip install boto3
!pip install requests_aws4auth
!pip install langchain
!pip install opensearch-py
!pip install langchain-community

import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from langchain.vectorstores import OpenSearchVectorSearch
from langchain.embeddings import BedrockEmbeddings
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection

host_url = "https://search-pensearchhosto"
aws_auth = AWS4Auth("authy_key", "auth_secreate","ap-south-1", "es", session_token=None)

bedrock_client = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id="authy_key",
            aws_secret_access_key="auth_secreate",
            region_name="us-east-1"
        ).client("bedrock-runtime", "us-east-1")
bedrock_embeddings = BedrockEmbeddings(model_id="amazon.titan-embed-text-v1", client=bedrock_client)

search_obj = OpenSearchVectorSearch(
    opensearch_url=host_url,
    index_name="db",
    embedding_function=bedrock_embeddings,
    ssl_show_warn=False,
    http_auth=aws_auth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection,
    is_aoss=True
)


search_query="why handwriting?"
pre_filter={'bool': {'must': [
    {'simple_query_string': 
     {'query': '"1165540"|"1061875"|"1061876"|"1061877"|"1061878"|"1061879"|"1061880"|"1061881"|"1061882"|"1061883"|"1061884"|"1056632"|"1055768"',
      'fields': ['metadata.file_id']
     }
    },
    {'simple_query_string': 
     {'query': 3948,
      'fields': ['metadata.client_ref']
     }
    },
    ],
}}

result :

[Document(page_content="document text ': ['tag 1']}),

need a solution or alternative for this questions
